# SQLAlchemy: getting columns of some type

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to look at the columns of some tables I have and dynamically filter for just text columns. How can I do this with SQLAlchemy? So far, I have this:

```
for table in tables:
    columns = Table(table, meta).columns
```

How can I filter `columns` down to just text columns?

SQLAlchemy version: 1.1.0b1
Python version: 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

The column has attribute 'typev, and 'type' has attribute 'python_type'. You can use it to filter by:

```
col.type.python_type == str
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This can be done as follows:

str_columns = filter(lambda column: isinstance(column.type, TEXT), columns)

Where `TEXT` is `sqlalchemy.TEXT`.